# How to output plain ascii from base64 decode?

Tags: c, base64, decoding

Encoded normal plain text `bmVv` decoded to `neo` without any issues but this
`AAAAgMom/1a/v0lblO2Ubrt60J2gcuXSljGFQXgcyZWveWLEwo6prwgi3iJIZdodyhKZQrNWp5nKJ3srRXcUW+F1BD3baEVGcmEgqaLZUNBjm057pKRI16kB0YppeGx5qIQ5QjKzsR8ETQbKLNWgRY0QRNVz34kMJR3P/LgHax/6rmf5AAAAAwEAAQ==`
encoded string is not decoding. Just getting output buffer `NULL`/`0`.
This string decoded buffer should be single character. If I do that then I will get unsigned decode ASCII, but that ASCII code just viewable and writeable, can't use encoder to encode again that ASCII code because I am still getting buffer length of `0`. It is because I used `printf` with `%c` to output buffer. It is not string to output using `%s`.

I need to output ASCII buffer as string. How is it possible to output ASCII buffer as string without using `%c` with `printf`/`fwrite`/`scanf`/`putchar`?

I expecting binary ASCII code as string to use again for encoding.

Expecting:

```
��&�V��I[��n�zН�r�Җ1�Axɕ�yb��"�"He���B�V���'{+Ew[�u=�hEFra ���P�c�N{��Hשъixly��9B2��M�,ՠE�D�s߉
                                             %���k��g�
```

Here is base64 decode full code that I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char base64_map[64] = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
    'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
    'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'
};

char *base64_decode(char *str)
{
    int counts = 0;
    char buffer[4];
    char *plain = malloc(strlen(str) * 3 / 4 + 1);
    int i = 0, p = 0;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < 64 && base64_map[k] != str[i]; k++);
        buffer[counts++] = k;

        if (counts == 4) {
            plain[p++] = (buffer[0] << 2) + (buffer[1] >> 4);

            if (buffer[2] != 64) {
                plain[p++] = (buffer[1] << 4) + (buffer[2] >> 2);
            }

            if (buffer[3] != 64) {
                plain[p++] = (buffer[2] << 6) + buffer[3];
            }

            counts = 0;
        }
    }

    plain[p] = '\0';

    return plain;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "AAAAgMom/1a/v0lblO2Ubrt60J2gcuXSljGFQXgcyZWveWLEwo6prwgi3iJIZdodyhKZQrNWp5nKJ3srRXcUW+F1BD3baEVGcmEgqaLZUNBjm057pKRI16kB0YppeGx5qIQ5QjKzsR8ETQbKLNWgRY0QRNVz34kMJR3P/LgHax/6rmf5AAAAAwEAAQ==";
    printf("%s", base64_decode(str));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be here, and why do you expect it to be that? What is your output instead? Does this compile? Does this run? Does this crash?

Comment: That base64 string decodes to binary data, you can't treat it as a string. You might consider printing the data as hex bytes to see what it decodes to.

Comment: Expecting like this ascii: ```��&�V��I[��n�zН�r�Җ1�Axɕ�yb��"�"He���B�V���'{+Ew[�u=�hEFra ���P�c�N{��Hשъixly��9B2��M�,ՠE�D�s߉
                                             %���k��g�```

Comment: I think your decoder is fine.  I tested it on 100 strings, of random lengths, and it always decoded perfectly.  Try it on `SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQo=`.

Comment: That isn't ASCII. The first 3 bytes of the decoded string are 0 so printf sees an empty string. You could print character by character but what you see for characters outside the printable range is platform dependent.

Comment: �, ߉ՠ and ש, ߉ are not ASCII characters. You also have some text-direction unicode control characters in there (I think).

Comment: Where did you get that output string from? That will help us understand what encoding it has applied to it. Information = data + context. You have the data (base64 decode gives you a string of bytes), but we don't know how to interpret that data. **Where did you get that output string**? A better question **what encoding do you want to use to interpret your binary data?**

Comment: You can make this question better by editing out the entire base64 encode/decode part. Your question is really about character encoding and how to display/interpret binary data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're decoding binary data, as here, you can't print it using `printf`, because `printf` will stop at the first null byte.

To print binary data, you could have your `base64_decode` function return an explicit length, and then print that many characters.  Perhaps something like this:

```
int main()
{
    char *str = "…";
    int len;
    char *out = base64_decode(str, &len);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) putchar(out[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

To make that work you would rewrite `base64_decode`'s signature to

```
char *base64_decode(char *str, int *lenp)
```

and add the line

```
if(lenp != NULL) *lenp = p;
```

at the end, right before the `return plain;` statement.

Rather than the loop calling `putchar`, you could also use `fwrite`:

```
char *out = base64_decode(str, &len);
fwrite(out, 1, len, stdout);
```

And depending on what you're trying to do with the output, it would be easier to see (though perhaps not easier to process) if you output a hexadecimal representation of the bytes, rather than the bytes themselves:

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf("%02x", (unsigned char)out[i]);
```

Comment: stdout will allow me to encode decoded data again?

Comment: @MasudRana Yes.  You can redirect it to a file, or pipe it into another program.  (At least on Unix-like systems, including Linux and MacOS.  Not sure what your realistic options would be under Windows.)

Comment: What you implemented? plz share full code to understand goodly, thanks

Comment: @MasudRana you misunderstand the point of this site. https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: I tried as you did, its outputing but not sure to encode again, let me try to encode again

Comment: Do you have any idea, how php, golang, rust, python uses base64 decoder?

Comment: @MasudRana In general terms I do.  A fundamental property of any base64 decoder is that while its input is a *string*, its output is *arbitrary binary data*.  And in C, at least, working with arbitrary binary data is not quite as easy as working with ordinary strings.  I suspect that's what you're struggling with: choosing an appropriate representation for arbitrary binary data, and using that representation as input to your next stage of encoding/decoding.

Comment: That's why I added the note "depending on what you're trying to do with the output" at the end of my answer.  Using `printf("%02x")` might help you get a better feel for what's going on.  (But that change will probably *not* be what you ultimately need as "input to your next stage of encoding/decoding".) If there's a specific aspect of that next stage that you can describe, you might want to ask a separate question about it.

Comment: I said "A fundamental property of any base64 decoder is that while its input is a *string*, its output is *arbitrary binary data*."  What that means is that the output can and generally will contain arbitrary bytes, that (a) may not be human readable and (b) may not even be printable or (c) may be special in other ways, such as being the 0 byte that terminates C strings.  That's why you can't print arbitrary binary data using `printf("%s")`, and in general you can't print it at all, because you get garbage like `��&�V��I[��`.

Comment: Checkout this: https://github.com/blade-lang/blade/blob/main/src/standard/base64.c#L125 output returning as bytes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251339/discussion-between-masud-rana-and-steve-summit).